# eclipse launch configuration for web project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, launch, eclipse-wtp

So I right click on my project and choose "Run on server" and runs fine. But I cant seem to be able to move the run configuration (the `.launch` file) in my project - when I go to run configurations > Server tab I see the launch config for tomcat which if I run it launches Tomcat fine but does not display the index of my web app - which is displayed alright if I rclick on the project and choose "Run on server".

In `${workspace_loc}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches` I have both :

**Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost.launch** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.launchConfigurationType">
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH">
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry containerPath=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.7.0_03&quot; path=&quot;2&quot; type=&quot;4&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/_/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/bin/bootstrap.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/_/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/bin/tomcat-juli.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#13;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry externalArchive=&quot;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/lib/tools.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#13;&#10;"/>
</listAttribute>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.DEFAULT_CLASSPATH" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER" value="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jdk1.7.0_03"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROGRAM_ARGUMENTS" value="start"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.VM_ARGUMENTS" value="-Dcatalina.base=&quot;C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces\javaEE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1&quot; -Dcatalina.home=&quot;C:\_\apache-tomcat-7.0.32&quot; -Dwtp.deploy=&quot;C:\Dropbox\eclipse_workspaces\javaEE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps&quot; -Djava.endorsed.dirs=&quot;C:\_\apache-tomcat-7.0.32\endorsed&quot;"/>
<stringAttribute key="server-id" value="Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

and my web app's .launch (**ted2012.launch**) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.launchConfigurationType">
<stringAttribute key="client-id" value="org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.web"/>
<stringAttribute key="launchable-adapter-id" value="org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.web"/>
<stringAttribute key="module-artifact" value="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ted2012//"/>
<stringAttribute key="module-artifact-class" value="org.eclipse.wst.server.core.util.WebResource"/>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
<listEntry value="/ted2012"/>
</listAttribute>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_TYPES">
<listEntry value="4"/>
</listAttribute>
<stringAttribute key="server-id" value="Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

which however does not appear in my launches :

[image: eclipse launches]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked in the WTP forums and [got](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/452775/1008087/#msg_1008087)

> Server launches are "different". The launch is created/regenerated
>   based on your server configuration each time you start the server.
>   Some pieces of an existing launch are preserved, such as VM Arguments,
>   but otherwise the launch gets replaced each time the server is
>   started. As a result, moving the launch file to an alternate location
>   isn't supported. It always ends up under
>   "org.eclipse.debug.core.launches".

Still looking for this piece of info in the docs - so if anyone knows this I might accept it as an answer - I will accept also an educated bug report - as the situation qualifies at least for an enhancement. Closing for now